# How to do a get request with parameters [NODE.JS]

Tags: node.js

Thank you for reading. It has litteraly been hours that i've been searching for my problem: as said in the title didn't found anything even looked at docs of nodejs but there isn't what i'm searching so it's weird seems like no one does that?

```js
const https = require("https")

https.request("http://aratools.com/dict-service?query=%7B%22dictionary%22%3A%22AR-EN-WORD-DICTIONARY%22%2C%22word%22%3A%22%D9%86%D8%B9%D9%85%22%2C%22dfilter%22%3Atrue%7D&format=json&_=1643219263345",
    (res) => {
        console.log(res)
    }
)
```

the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stvTU.png)

website used: http://aratools.com/
Trying to do experiment thing later on (have something in head but first have to manage to do this get request)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module instead of https.

```js
const http = require("http")
        
http.request("http://aratools.com/dict-service?query=%7B%22dictionary%22%3A%22AR-EN-WORD-DICTIONARY%22%2C%22word%22%3A%22%D9%86%D8%B9%D9%85%22%2C%22dfilter%22%3Atrue%7D&format=json&_=1643219263345", (res) => {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Comment: Oh, right! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `https` in the URL and not `http` if you're using the package `https`. Otherwise you should use the package `http`.

Comment: Oh, makes sense! Thanks